# My Custom Column "QR Code" Don't Have Data in my CSV Export

Tags: magento2

I added a QR Code column in my admin grid, where I concatenate my order_id and increment_id.

```
class QrCode extends Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {   
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $increment_id = $items['increment_id'];
                $order_id = $items['order_id'];

                $items['qrcode'] = $increment_id." ".$order_id;           
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It worked and displayed in my admin grid perfectly but it won't show when I export it to CSV. What should I do?

Comment: Hope this will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184040/magento-2-custom-column-added-sku-on-grid-not-showing-data-in-export-file

Answer (score 0):

In order to add your custom column `QrCode` to the export csv, You need to override and extend the class `Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv` and rewrite the method `getCsvFile` to include your custom field `QrCode`

**source**

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/app/code/Magento/Ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php

---

**Sample Code** (not tested, you must correct this based on your needs)

**Your Module (DI) file**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="StackExchange\Override\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" />
</config>
```

Overriden Class **ConvertToCsv.php**

> app/code/StackExchange/Override/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Rewritten Export Model Convert To CSV class to include the custom field added to the grid
 * 
 *  
 * @author Jerome Dennis <haijerome@gmail.com>
 * 
 */
namespace StackExchange\Override\Model\Export\;

class ConvertToCsv extends \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv
{
    /**
 * Returns CSV file
 *
 * @return array
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function getCsvFile()
{
    $component = $this->filter->getComponent();

    $name = md5(microtime());
    $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';

    // Here goes your code to include your custom field QrCode 

    return [
        'type' => 'filename',
        'value' => $file,
        'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
    ];
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

As alternate solutions, you can also use the [solution provided here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283476/695) or [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243866/695)